# Regex to check of consecutive occurrence of same digit ignoring white spaces

Tags: regex

I am writing a regex to check the consecutive occurrence of same digit in a number ignoring the white space between.

I have written `1{2,}|2{2,}|3{2,}|4{2,}|5{2,}|6{2,}|7{2,}|8{2,}|9{2,}|0{2,}`

but this only checks if the occurrences don't have a space in between. How can I change it be ignore white spaces in between?

Test case:

1234 5678 9876 6543
2155 2174 9832 1349
4389 1234 5678 9876

in these test cases it should match 1st and second. 1st contains two 6s with a space in between. Second is a general case with two consecutive 5's
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some example strings and flavour of regex u r using?

Comment: @vks added text cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(\d)(?:\s*\1)+
```

Digit; then any number of spaces, then same digit - once or more.